# Store Jquery object and access later?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to store Jquery object into an array and access later to apply Jquery methods.

Something like:

```
var myArr = [];
myArr.push($('div#id1'));
myArr.push($('div#id2'));
$(myArr).show();
```

This is not working

Comment: To start with, what's logged if you add `console.log(myArr)` just above the .show() line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on storing your jQuery objects in an array, you will need to map that array to a new jQuery object before being able to call jQuery methods on it to affect your stored objects.

You can use jQuery's [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) for that:

```
var myArr = [];
myArr.push($('div#id1'));
myArr.push($('div#id2'));

$(myArr).map(function(){ return this.toArray(); }).show();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7hetpkhp/)

Comment: I didn't. Not sure who is this?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to execute the `show` method on the array passed to `jQuery`, not on each object, try something like this:

```
$.each(myArr, function(k, elem) {
  $(elem).show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing the items in an array to begin with? If you only need to perform operations over multiple items you can simply do either of the following:

```
$('selector1, selector2').operation();
$('selector1').add('selector2').operation();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, all JQueried ^^ :

```
var myElements = $('div#id1');
myElements = myElements.add('div#id2');

myElements.show();
```

To reverse the .add() you can use .not :

```
myElements = myElements.not('.clazz');

myElements.hide();
```